# Python list to django javascript as text

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-3.x

Hello my generated python output list is

```
l = ["one","two","there"]
```

I am passing that to a django html script as {{list}}

in the html it is shown as

```
[&#39;one&#39;,&#39;two&#39;,&#39;three&#39;
```

which i can't use for my javascript, how do i pass this correctly, even I tried json_dumps like

```
l = json_dumps (["one","two","there"])
```

it just shows as following in html

```
[&quote;one&quote;,&quote;two&quote;,&quote;three&quote;]
```

Comment: How are you passing that to the template? Please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: yes, I have done those correctly . Daniel Rosema's method works 

    {{list|safe}} 

instead of 
    {{list}}

anyway thanks for the comment Sayse ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps here. Firstly, you need to make the view send valid JSON; you've done this with `json_dumps`.

Secondly, you need to ensure that the template outputs it without escaping. You do that by marking it as safe, with `{{ data|safe }}` (assuming your data is in a variable called `data`).

Comment: Hi Daniel can you give me your twitter of fb ..It's nice to be connected with you ..